# Stay Highlighted the Selected item in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]I got an issue when I'm highlighting the selected item in ExpandableListView.

My code correctly highlights the selected item. But the problem is now showing the custom layout text. IE, can't to see the TextView wich in list_group.xml and list_item.xml

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector = "@drawable/jsk"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    />
```

my list_selector is jsk.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

</selector>
```

list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Adapter class is,

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

How to solve my issue?

Comment: @Satish Kumar your problem is that you can not see the text when list item is hightlighted. am i right ?

Comment: yeah yes @nitintyagi

Comment: you can do a couple of things : first change your text color.

Comment: @nitin tyagi  i also tried .  text color is changed, but again same problem. cant see my text when selected item is highlighted.

Comment: ok..can u please change the highlighted to transparent .

Comment: if i change to transparent means, how to differentiate the highlighted item color?

Comment: @Satish , it just only for check . if your text is visible with transparent color then the problem in your highlighted color.   Can you please tell me what you are using for highlight. its a color or any drawable ?

Comment: drawable see my edited post (added jsk.xml) for list_selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the line,

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

at **activity_main.xml** and also remove the line

```
android:background="#000000"
```

for group_item selection indicator.

these two steps solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For that selected `TextView` dont set textColor from **selector**, just add selector for it in xml.

**textview_color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />   
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" /> <!-- default case -->
</selector>
```

**listitem.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_color_selector"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />        
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no changes after adding textview_color_selector.xml @Arun Shankar . see my screen shot. it shows selector will occupies the child item background color. i cant see the textColor.